# Predicting Lifetimes using CoxPH

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

I have a dataset of about 9k rows and 60 features (columns). I have a binary status column (1 - dead, 0 - alive) and a lifetime column in days which is right censored. I am currently using the cox-PH model on this data and getting a probability score for each of my rows. However my ultimate goal is to predict the expected lifetimes for the not yet dead (status=0) samples.

In R I am trying:

```
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(lifetime, status) ~ F1 + F2 +..., data=df)
preds <- survfit(res.cox, newdata=df)
median_expectations <- summary(preds)$table[,"median"]
```

In Python I tried the same using [lifelines](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/) library:

```
cf = CoxPHFitter()
cf.fit(df, 'lifetime', event_col='status')
predicted = cf.predict_expectation(df).values[:, 0]
```

I am getting a high **concordance value of 0.9** both in R and Python. However my predicted lifetimes are all over the place. Even on the training set itself. Mean absolute difference is quite high. Is cox-PH the right model for my problem? If yes, what am I doing wrong? If not, what other models should I look at?